# Issues with firebase google-Oauth logout in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am facing an issue in my React app when implementing Google Auth using Firebase. After a successful login, I need to check if the user exists in my Firebase database. If the user does not exist, I log them out. The issue I am facing is that after logging out, I am unable to sign in again as the authentication popup does not appear. I believe this can be due to caching of the current user in the browser.

Here's my current signInWithGoogle function:

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      console.log(result.user)
      const mailId = result.user.email ? result.user.email:""
      const Isvalid = await validate(mailId);
    if (Isvalid) {
        console.log('validated user')
        navigate('/dashboard')
    } else {
      signOut(auth).then(() => {
          console.log('Signout Successful');
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('Error', err);
        })
        alert('not a valid user')
      }
    }
```

Comment: And do you get any errors in the browser console? If yes, can you please share a screenshot of the logs?

Comment: No I do not get any errors. Only console.logs messages, as they should be without any ambiguity.
Also only way to login again is to close the tab and then open again. If I try to do in different tab without closing previous one, it didn't worked. That's why I feel its issue of browser caching the logged in user details.